# How to get an Image url after image crop, instead of a blob url

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a react code and using react-image-crop to to crop the images being uploaded. I have a dropzone for image. So, whenever a image is dropped, the FileReader reads the image and when loading is complete, I get encoded base64 dataUrl. 
Now, when I crop this image, I get a blob url, as, 
blob:http://localhost:3000/bc361b08-589f-430b-a71e-b0bc3b59fd1a

```
// For reading and cropping the image
onSelectFile = e => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", () =>
                this.setState({ src: reader.result })
            );
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

    // If you setState the crop in here you should return false.
    onImageLoaded = image => {
        this.imageRef = image;
    };

    onCropComplete = crop => {
        this.makeClientCrop(crop);
    };

    onCropChange = (crop, percentCrop) => {
        this.setState({ crop });
    };

    async makeClientCrop(crop) {
        if (this.imageRef && crop.width && crop.height) {
            const croppedImageUrl = await this.getCroppedImg(
                this.imageRef,
                crop,
                "newFile.jpeg"
            );
            this.setState({ croppedImageUrl });
        }
        console.log(this.state.croppedImageUrl, "myResult croppedImageUrl")
    }

    getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
        const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
        canvas.width = crop.width;
        canvas.height = crop.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(
            image,
            crop.x * scaleX,
            crop.y * scaleY,
            crop.width * scaleX,
            crop.height * scaleY,
            0,
            0,
            crop.width,
            crop.height
        );

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                if (!blob) {
                    //reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
                    return;
                }
                blob.name = fileName;
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.fileUrl);
                this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                resolve(this.fileUrl);
            }, "image/jpeg");
        });
    }

onDrop = (files, rejectedFiles) => {
        const self = this

        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })

        if (!!rejectedFiles && !!rejectedFiles.length) {
            this.verifyFile(rejectedFiles)
            this.setState({
                dropZoneClassName: 'dropzone-error',
                loading: false,
                error: true
            })
            return
        }

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            const isVerified = this.verifyFile(files)
            if (isVerified) {
                this.setState({
                    dropZoneClassName: 'dropzone-success'
                })
                // imageBase64Data 
                const currentFile = files[0]
                const myFileItemReader = new FileReader()
                myFileItemReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    const myResult = myFileItemReader.result
                    console.log(myResult, "myResult")
                    const e = myResult.slice(5, myResult.length)
                    console.log(e, "myResult after slice")
                    this.setState({
                        imgSrc: myResult,
                        imgSrcExt: extractImageFileExtensionFromBase64(myResult),
                        src: myResult,
                        newSrc: e
                    })
                }, false)

                myFileItemReader.readAsDataURL(currentFile)
            }
        }
    }

onImageClick = (e) => {
        console.log(e, "myResult croppedImageUrl")
        if (!e) {
            return
        }
        e = this.state.croppedImageUrl
        const self = this
        this.props.uploadProfileImage('', '', this.state.croppedImageUrl).then(function ({ payload }) {
            self.setState({
                loading: false,
                dropZoneClassName: '',
                error: false,
            })

            self.state.onUpload(e)
        })
    }
```

Expected Result : The cropped image should get uploaded to the server.

Actual Result : The image is not being uploaded because it is a blob.

Is it possible to not get a blob after cropping and instead get a normal url?

Comment: Put the blob into a file and return a url then?

Comment: @emix Can you please elaborate? How can I do it?

Comment: Please [show at least some](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+js+save+blob+to+a+file) effort. I'm not going to do this for you. 1) create a file inside an accessible location 2) base64 decode the content of the blob 3) put it inside the file 4) return a url